# How to clearfix this image fader?

Tags: javascript, css

```js
(function($) {
        var $panoramas = $('#header_rotator').children();
        var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * $panoramas.length);
        $panoramas.eq(index).show();

        setInterval(function() {
            $panoramas.eq(index).fadeOut(1000);
            index = (index + 1) % $panoramas.length;
            $panoramas.eq(index).fadeIn(1000);
        }, 5000);
    })(jQuery);
```

```css
#header_rotator {
  position: relative;
  background-color: black;
}
#header_rotator .panorama-outer {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
}
#header_rotator .panorama-outer .panorama-inner {
  position: relative;
}
#header_rotator .panorama-outer .panorama-inner img {
  max-width: 733px;
  width: 100%;
}
#header_rotator .panorama-outer .panorama-inner .header_caption {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: white;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.75);
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header_rotator">
     <div class="panorama-outer">
        <div class="panorama-inner">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/733/200/cats/1" alt="Alt text">

            <div class="header_caption">Cat 1</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panorama-outer">
        <div class="panorama-inner">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/733/200/cats/2" alt="Alt text">

            <div class="header_caption">Cat 2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panorama-outer">
        <div class="panorama-inner">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/733/200/cats/3" alt="Alt text">

            <div class="header_caption">Cat 3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panorama-outer">
        <div class="panorama-inner">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/733/200/cats/4" alt="Alt text">

            <div class="header_caption">Cat 4</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panorama-outer">
        <div class="panorama-inner">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/733/200/cats/5" alt="Alt text">

            <div class="header_caption">Cat 5</div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<p>some text below</p>
```

I wrote this little image fader, but I'm not sure how to get the "some text below" to get pushed down. The #header_rotator has 0 height because its contents are absolute positioned, but they need to be absolute positioned so that the images stack.

I can't hardcode the height of the #header_rotator because it needs to be squishable (responsive).

So what can I do to fix the height of #header_rotator?

Comment: Clearfixes are for floats. Since there isn't anything floating in there, they won't help! The sad truth is that you will need to give the #header_rotator div some height. Ehm, responsively. How do you "squish" it? In a @media query?

Comment: Yeah, I know a "clearfix" won't work, but I thought the term would help describe my intent. There's actually no media queries necessary for this -- look at the style on `img`: `width` is set to `100%`. If you shrink your browser, the image will be automatically be shrunk proportionately. Stackoverflow's preview doesn't really let you do that --  try playing with panels on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mnpenner/ggya4o15/).

Answer (score 1):

If the pictures are always 733×200 pixels in size, the solution is as follows.

Give the `#header_rotator` a bottom padding of 200px if the window is wider, and 27% if the window is narrower. 27% is the width to height ratio of the pictures, and it works because padding in percent is a percentage of the width of the window rather than the height.

So,

```css
#header_rotator {
  position: relative;
  background-color: black;
  padding-bottom:27%;  /* this line is added in at the top */
}

...

@media (min-width:733px) { /* this is new */
  #header_rotator {
   width:733px;
   padding-bottom:200px
  }
}
```

See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/ggya4o15/1/).

If the pictures are NOT always 733×200 pixels, you may be able to do something similar, but maybe using Javascript to find out the dimensions.